# Constructing two classes using each other

Tags: c++, oop

For example there are classes A and B. A uses B's methods and *vice versa*. So, what is usually done is passing a pointer to an object of the other class in the constructor.

But what if they use each other – how should I pass B to A if B is not yet constructed? Ok, I wrote setter for A and call it after both are created. Now I don't use any B's code in A constructor, but it may change. What should I do then?

```
class A;
class B;

// A uses B
class A {
    B* b;
public:
    A() {
        // potentially calls b's methods
    }
    void setB(B* b) { this->b = b; }
}

// B uses A
class B {
    A* a;
public:
    B(A* a) : a(a) {
        // potentially calls a's methods
    }
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b(&a);
    a.setB(&b); // ugly, but no alternative?
    // Other classes use a and b
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an unusual design pattern. If I had to do this, I would put the logic in a factory. You can't create both objects at the same time, one must come first.

Comment: Why are they separate objects if each needs to use the other and have exactly one opposite number?

Comment: As the OP has it - yes unusual. However, two, mutually-dependent classes is not, in itself, an unusual pattern; think of the Windows/MFC "document-view" paradigm.

Comment: @DavisHerring These classes have different logic and purposes and can be used separately in further code, this is just simplified example. Honestly, i thought this problem is quite usual and there's some workaround.

Comment: If you have two objects that each try to call member functions of each other with neither fully constructed, then your design is flawed.   Assuming construction of the `A` starts first, the constructor of `A` somehow needs to construct `B` before calling the `B`s member functions.  (Opposite order if construction of `B` occurs first).   It is not possible for the two objects to be constructed in parallel, and for the constructors of each to be able to call members of each other - one of the objects must be constructed first.

Answer (score 3):

Either the chicken, or the egg, must come first. One of these objects must be created before the other one.

There are only two ways to cheat:

1. Declare both objects in global scope and use forward declarations:

   ```
    extern A a;
    extern B b;

    A a{&b};
    B b{&a};
   ```

Note that `a` still gets constructed before `b`, so invoking `b`'s methods in `a`'s constructor will be undefined behavior. But merely saving a pointer to the object is fine.

2. A variation of this is to construct both objects as member of a third object, and basically do the same thing in the object's constructor:

   ```
    struct C {
        A a;
        B b;
        C() : a{&b}, b{&a} {}
    };
   ```

Now, instantiating `C` in automatic or dynamic scope will instantiate both objects, passing each other's address to their respective constructors. But you still can't avoid the fundamental C++ property that only one object gets constructed at a time (in the same execution thread).

Answer (score 2):

You can address *part* of your problem by defining the constructors (or any other methods that use members or methods of the other class) "out of body" – that is, put just the declaration(s) in the body of the class definitions, then define those actual methods *after both classes have been fully specified*. But that won't address the issue you have of both constructors needing pointers to the other.

Here's a possible code arrangement:

```cpp
class A;
class B;

// A uses B
class A {
    B* b;
public:
    A(B* arg_b = nullptr); // Declaration only - defined later!
    void setB(B* arg_b) {
        b = arg_b;
    }
    void foo() { } // Dummy test function
};

// B uses A
class B {
    A* a;
public:
    B(A* arg_a = nullptr); // Declaration only - defined later!
    void bar() { } // Dummy test function
};

// We provide the actual DEFINITIONS of the constructors after both classes have been specified...

A::A(B* arg_b) : b(arg_b)
{
    if (b != nullptr) b->bar(); // Potentially uses one of B's methods
}

B::B(A* arg_a) : a(arg_a)
{
    if (a != nullptr) a->foo(); // Potentially uses one of A's methods
}

int main()
{
    A a; // This will initialize "a" with a default (null) pointer to its contained "B"
    B b(&a);
    a.setB(&b); // Can't really get round this - chickens, eggs and all that!
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

You could also add/copy the relevant code from the constructor into the `setB` function, and (similarly) place that definition after both classes:

```cpp
void A::setB(B* arg_b)
{
    b = arg_b;
    if (b != nullptr) b->bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it that :

By creating a third class AB that creates an A and a B in it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B;

struct A
{
    B* b;
    void print() { std::cout << "A"; }
};

struct B
{
    A* a;
    void print() { std::cout << "B"; }
};

struct AB
{
    A a;
    B b;
    AB() : a{&b} , b{&a} {}
};
```

Then you can use structure binding to extract the A and B from AB:

```
int main()
{
    auto [a, b] = AB{};
    a.print();
    b.print();
}
```

Similarly, you can have a function that returns a `std::pair<A, B>`:

```
auto create_AB()
{
    A a;
    B b{&a};
    a.b = &b;
    return std::make_pair(a, b);
}
```

And in main:

```
auto [a, b] = create_AB();
```